# Basic Socket Programming in C

Tags: c, sockets, if-statement

So I am having a weird problem that I have been facing in my program that is basically a client/server socket programming example in C. I have taken time away from the problem, but I cannot seem to locate what is causing the problem.

If needed, I can post more details, but following is what is not working.

```
       while(1)
{
char word[256];
gets(word);
printf("%s",word);

     if(strcmp(word, "TRANSLATE") == 0 || strcmp(word, "GET") == 0 ||strcmp(word, "STORE") == 0 || strcmp(word, "EXIT") == 0)
{
    if(strcmp(word, "TRANSLATE") == 0)
    {
        if(send(sock , word , strlen(word) , 0)<0)
        {
            printf("Send Error\n");
            return 1;
        }
        bzero(server_reply,2000);
        if(recv(sock , server_reply , 2000 , 0)<0)
        {
            puts("Recieving Error\n");
        }
        //Print out 200ok message
        printf("%s\n", server_reply);
        //Get the first word
        gets(word2);
        while(strcmp(word2,"." )!= 0)
        {

            if(send(sock , word2 , strlen(word2) , 0)<0)
            {
                printf("Send Error\n");
                return 1;
            }
            gets(word2);    
        }
        if(recv(sock , server_reply , 2000 , 0)<0)
        {
            puts("Recieving Error\n");
        }
            printf("%s\n", server_reply);
        //STILL NEED TO WORK ON PARSING OUT SPACES BECAUSE RESULT IS IN A STRING, JUST WITH SPACES.
        //ALSO NEED TO DO SERVER SIDE CAPITALIZATION
    }
    if(strcmp(word, "GET") == 0)
    {

        printf("Getting");
    /*
        if(send(sock , word , strlen(word) , 0)<0)
        {
            printf("Send Error\n");
            return 1;
        }
        bzero(server_reply,2000);
        if(recv(sock , server_reply , 2000 , 0)<0)
        {
            puts("Recieving Error\n");
        }
        //Print out 200ok message
        printf("%s\n", server_reply);
        /*
         if(recv(sock , server_reply , 2000 , 0)<0)
        {
            puts("Recieving Error\n");
        }
        //Print out the KANSAS message
        printf("%s\n", server_reply);
        */
    }
}
```

The code breaks once I uncomment in the "GET" selection, and it doesn't even hit the printf() statement before the if statement.If I leave it out it hits all the proper statements perfectly. Am I missing something?
Also, I am thinking it may be something with the server communication, so this is the server code.

```
  #include<stdio.h>
  #include<string.h>  //strlen
#include<sys/socket.h>
#include<arpa/inet.h>   //inet_addr
#include<unistd.h>  //write

int main(int argc , char *argv[])
{
   int socket_desc , client_sock , c , read_size;
   struct sockaddr_in server , client;
   char client_message[2000];

   //Create socket
   socket_desc = socket(AF_INET , SOCK_STREAM , 0);
   if (socket_desc == -1)
   {
       printf("Could not create socket");
   }
   puts("Socket created");

   //Prepare the sockaddr_in structure
   server.sin_family = AF_INET;
   server.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
   server.sin_port = htons( 5149 );

   //Bind
   if( bind(socket_desc,(struct sockaddr *)&server , sizeof(server)) < 0)
   {
       //print the error message
       printf("bind failed. Error");
       return 1;
   }
   puts("bind done");

   //Listen
   listen(socket_desc , 3);

   //Accept and incoming connection
   puts("Waiting for incoming connections...");
   c = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);

   //accept connection from an incoming client
   client_sock = accept(socket_desc, (struct sockaddr *)&client, (socklen_t*)&c);
   if (client_sock < 0)
   {
       printf("accept failed");
       return 1;
   }
   puts("Connection accepted");

   //Receive a message from client
   while( (read_size = recv(client_sock , client_message , 2000 , 0)) > 0 )
   {
    if(strcmp(client_message,"TRANSLATE")==0)
    {
        *(client_message + read_size) = '\0';
        char word[256]="200 OK TRANSLATE";
        write(client_sock, word, strlen(word));
        /*
         while( (read_size = recv(client_sock , client_message , 2000 , 0)) > 0 )
         {
            *(client_message + read_size) = '\0';
            puts(client_message);
            write(client_sock,client_message,strlen(client_message));
            if(strcmp(client_message,".")==0)
            {
                printf("breaking");
                break;
            }
            printf("IN while loop");
         }

        printf("Out of while loop");
        */
    }
    if(strcmp(client_message,"GET")==0)
    {
        *(client_message + read_size) = '\0';
        char word[256]="200 OK GET";
        write(client_sock, word , strlen(word));
        char word2[256]="I don't think we're in Kansas anymore.";
        write(client_sock, word2 , strlen(word2));
    }
    if(strcmp(client_message,"STORE")==0)
    {
        char word[256]="200 OK STORE";
        write(client_sock, word , strlen(word));
    }
   }

   if(read_size == 0)
   {
       puts("Client disconnected");
       fflush(stdout);
   }
   else if(read_size == -1)
   {
       printf("recv failed");
   }

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Did you `strace` both client & server programs?

Comment: I have not, I am very new to Linux programming, and am just trying to figure out why the if statement breaks down if i include directly copied from the translate statement, which works fine by istelf

Comment: Don't use `gets`. It is unsafe and has been removed from the C standard.

Answer (score 3):

You should add a `\n` at end of every `printf` format control string and/or call [fflush(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fflush.3.html)

The main issue in your program is the wrong belief that a given `send` (or `write`) to a [socket(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/socket.7.html) corresponds to a single `recv` (or `read`) on the other side.

A [tcp(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/tcp.7.html) implementation is just a *stream of bytes* ; there is no implicit message boundaries. So your application should *buffer* and explicitly split that stream into meaningful messages.

It *could* happen, and it *does* happen, that one side is able to `send` or `write` 4000 bytes at once followed by another emission of 1000 bytes, but the other side would first `recv` (or `read`) e.g. 39 bytes, then 1 byte, then 1960 bytes then 3000 bytes. You then understand that "messages" are not intact, there is only a stream of bytes.

<sup>An additional difficulty is that such behavior is not reproducible. The next time you'll run your server and client programs they will behave differently!</sup>

In practice, it is helpful to define well where are the message boundaries. You could do like in [HTTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol), i.e. put some content length (in HTTP, the `Content-Length:` attribute in reply headers) in the beginning of each message. You could also decide that a message is a single long line with a single newline terminating it (and then, you could need a convention to escape internal newlines), look e.g. at [JSON](http://json.org/). And of course you should buffer on both sides.

You might want to test the readability or writability of a socket (or a pipe) with a multiplexing call like [poll(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/poll.2.html) (perhaps in your [event loop](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event_loop))

I strongly suggest to read [Advanced Linux Programming](http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/) and some [Linux Socket Tutorial](http://www.tenouk.com/cnlinuxsockettutorials.html).

BTW, always test your syscalls for failure. See [intro(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/intro.2.html) and use [perror(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/perror.3.html) or [errno(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/errno.3.html) (often with [strerror(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strerror.3.html)).

Of course compile with all warnings and debug info (`gcc -Wall -g`) and use the debugger (`gdb`) (and perhaps also [strace(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/strace.1.html)). You might want to debug with *two* `gdb` sessions (one for the server, one for the client) in different terminals.

BTW, don't use the obsolete *deprecated* [`bzero`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/bzero.3.html) function, use the standard [memset(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/memset.3.html) instead.

Comment: Even if I am controlling the other server, and know the server is responding? This is a very basic, controlled communication, and it works fine in translate?

Comment: Yes, in particular routers between emitter & receiver (e.g. server & client) could fragment or coalesce packets.

Comment: Like Im trying to explain I guess, the first and most noticable error is once i uncomment out up to the print server_reply in the get command, the entire if statement breaks down, it doesnt even printf("Getting"); before it. The client just breaks. The server doesnt get any notifications at all.

Comment: @eso92: Did you compile with `gcc -Wall -g`) and use the `gdb` debugger?

Comment: How does "the client just breaks"? Did you debug that with `gdb` ?

Comment: I got it working, basically what was happening was typing in the get command would do nothing. It turns out to be for some reason transmitting GET over the server would almost never result in the server receiving the right message. Seeing as this a project, I just changed the command name to GETTING and it is now working flawlessly. I plan on debugging after I have submitted a gradable assignment.

Comment: Wrong approach: debugging with the debugger is the first thing you should know.

Comment: Unless you fix the issues described, you assignment will be graded low, even if it appears to work. Your prof/TA will have seen all the common causes of TCP problems many times and will immediately go hunting for them.