# How can I send an HTTP response using Linux raw sockets in c

Tags: c, linux, http, webserver, raw-sockets

Lately I have been trying to code a webserver using linux raw sockets in c, for the point of education. If my understanding is correct, this is how the ideal server should act:

```
       |  [SYN]        |
       |<--------------|
       |  [SYN] [ACK]  |
       |-------------->|
       |  [ACK]        |
       |<--------------|
       |GET / HTTP/1.1 |
       |<--------------|
       |  [ACK]        |
       |-------------->|
Server |HTTP/1.1 200 OK| Client
       |-------------->|
       |  [ACK]        |
       |<--------------|
       |  [FIN] [ACK]  |
       |<--------------|
       |  [FIN] [ACK]  |
       |-------------->|
       |  [ACK]        |
       |<--------------|
       |  [ACK]        |
       |-------------->|
```

However, trying to actually implememt this is a lot harder than it looks. Right now, I have code that can get up to the acknowledgement to the HTTP request without any problems. However, I cannot find anywhere on the internet that explains how to send the actual response. I have tried so many things, but nothing I can find will work. Here is how I am filling out the packet:

```
//allocate a packet to send:
uint8_t* httppack=(uint8_t*)malloc(IP_MAXPACKET*sizeof(uint8_t));
//allocate and fill out the payload:
char* payload=malloc(100*sizeof(char));
payload="HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\nConnection: close\r\nContent-Type: text/html\r\n\r\n<!doctype html><html><head><title>Evan's Webpage</title></head><body><h1>Evan's Webpage</h1></body></html>\r\n";
int payloadlen=strlen(payload);

//IP header

struct ip* iph=(struct ip*)httppack;
iph->ip_hl = 20/sizeof(uint32_t);
iph->ip_v = 4;
iph->ip_tos = 0;
//Flags: none set
iph->ip_off = htons ((0 << 15) + (0 << 14) + (0 << 13) +  0);
iph->ip_ttl = 255;
iph->ip_p = IPPROTO_TCP;
if (inet_pton (AF_INET, "192.168.1.141", &(iph->ip_src)) != 1) {
    printf("Failed to convert source IP to network form\n");
    exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
}
if (inet_pton (AF_INET, "192.168.1.114", &(iph->ip_dst)) != 1) {
    printf("Failed to convert target IP to network form\n");
    exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
}
//Since we don't know the checksum yet, make it zero:
iph->ip_sum = 0;
//Length is IP header (20) + TCP header (no options, 20) and payload
iph->ip_len = htons (20+20+payloadlen);
//ID is 2 because it is the third packet being sent (first was 0)
iph->ip_id = htons (2);
//IP Checksum function (I did not include it in this example, just assume that it works)
iph->ip_sum = chksm ((uint16_t *)iph, 20);

//TCP header

struct tcphdr* tcph=(struct tcphdr*)(httppack+sizeof(struct ip));
//source: http
tcph->source = htons (80);
//reserved: 0
tcph->res1 = 0;
//TCP header size: 20 (no options)
tcph->doff = 20/4;
tcph->rst = 0;
tcph->urg = 0;
tcph->res2 = 0;
//Window: max size
tcph->window = htons (65535);
tcph->urg_ptr = htons (0);
//We dont know what port the client will be requesting from at first. receivetcph is the TCP header of the last packet we received (HTTP request) so the dest port will be wherever that packet was sent from
tcph->dest = receivetcph->source;
// The sequence will simply be whatever the last packet's ack sequence was (Which will be 1)
tcph->seq = receivetcph->ack_seq;
//The acknowledgement sequence is the HTTP request packet's sequence (htseq) + the amount of data we received - ethernet header - IP header - TCP header (rsize). I am fairly confident this is not the problem with my code, so assume that it works
tcph->ack_seq = htonl(htseq+rsize);
//TCP Flags: ACK and PSH
tcph->syn = 0;
tcph->fin = 0;
tcph->ack = 1;
tcph->psh = 1;
//Another Checksum function, again, just assume it works
tcph->check = tcpchksm (*cip, *ctcp, (uint8_t*)payload, payloadlen);
//Copy payload to buffer before we send
memcpy((httppack+20+20), payload, payloadlen*sizeof(uint8_t));
```

But obviously this is wrong because the client does not acknowledge this packet when I send it, in fact it acts exactly as if I did not send the packet at all.

Questions:

-What is the correct way to fill out the HTTP response packet?

-What were the errors to the way I was filling it out?

-Finally, any advice about my code is appreciated (EXCEPT ADVICE TELLING ME TO STAY AWAY FROM RAW SOCKETS!!)

**EDIT:**
One last detail: when you use wire shark to sniff an http response being sent between a server and a client, it identifies the packet with an HTTP protocol, instead of a TCP protocol. I'd does not identify my packet as an HTTP protocol, and calls it a segment of a reassembled PDU. hopefully this will help you with question 2.

Thanks in advance

Comment: [Of course it's not simple](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616.txt)!

Comment: The HTTP protocol is complex (defined in hundreds of pages). Hence, HTTP client libraries (e.g. [libcurl](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/)...) or server libraries (e.g. [libonion](https://www.coralbits.com/libonion/)...) are complex - but since they are free software, you can study their source code. And TCP socket programs are *not* dealing with messages, but with streams; see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26085847/841108)

Comment: This isn't related to your problem but the two lines of code where you malloc and set the result to payload and then set payload to point to are a string are just wrong.  If you want to put the value of the string in the memory you just malloc'ed you need to copy it, what you have done is overwrite the pointer returned by malloc

Comment: ... the result is a wasted call to `malloc` and the inability to `free` the memory.

Comment: I realize that the http protocol is not simple, but I was under the impression that what I have as my payload is correct. Can you find anything wrong with it @BasileStarynkevitch?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wireshark

Comment: Well, i know that browsers don't like it if you don't tell them the `Content-Length` in the headers. Also, if you want this to work with modern browsers, and are testing with them, you should expect multiple connections. I know for me chromium made 3 connections when i made a server on a microcontroller. So test with `curl -v localhost:1234` and wireshark first.

Comment: I was under the impression that when browsers make multiple connections it was to get different files i.e. A css file or an image file @Davidvanrijn

Comment: True, but usually it will also try to get the `/favicon.ico` or something. You don't have to send it back, but it might mess up your tcp implementation.

Comment: But i also think there is a good reason that the network-stack is split up in mutliple layers. I would say your best bet is to first try to make tcp work and have it provide the standard `connect()` `accept()` etc functions, and if that works then you can just make it `listen()` and reply to sockets.